# How do I change the color of a pixel properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, jimp

I'm using `jimp` to manipulate an image. I'm trying to make something like a selection rectangle that when drawn has a transparent color (`#BBBBBBBB`). How do I calculate the `RGB` values I need to set for the pixels? I want to keep the old color and put the transparent color over it and sort of combine them. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I want to keep the old color and put the transparent color over it and sort of combine them. 
>  How can I do that?"*

You need **interpolation** on each color channel (R, G and B).

In blending color A with color B, you also need to select a point in the A-to-B path (ranging from 0 to 1). Interpolation gives you the color at that point. For example `0.5` is halfway so that point gives a 50/50 blend of two colors. Try it with colors Red and Blue (result is Purple color)

> *"How do I calculate the RGB values I need to set for the pixels?"*

```
var stepPoint = 0.5; //0.5 = 50% blend
var new_Red   = old_R + stepPoint * (transparent_R - old_R);
var new_Green = old_G + stepPoint * (transparent_G - old_G);
var new_Blue  = old_B + stepPoint * (transparent_B - old_B);

//# usage (after interpolation calculations)
some_Image_Data [i+0] = new_Red;
some_Image_Data [i+1] = new_Green;
some_Image_Data [i+2] = new_Blue;

//# or if you want to package as 32-bit integer of RGBA format
//var mixedColor = ( new_Red << 24) | ( new_Green << 16) | ( new_Blue << 8) | (255);
```

A faster/easier way might be to just adjust the **alpha** value of each pixel in the *"transparent"* image data. This way, when the pixel is set onto another imageData, it already has transparency.

```
var idx = 0; //# starting index position in bytes
while (true)
{
    if( idx >= some_Image_Data.length ) { break; }
    
    some_Image_Data[idx+3] = 128; //# set between 0-255... lower is more transparent
    idx += 4; //# move on to next pixel
}
```

Comment: It turned blue instead of gray

Comment: How to reproduce your result (_ie_: which A and B colors, what blend amount)?

Comment: well I just take a random image and want to apply the #bbbbbbbb color to certain parts of it (has alpha).